# Flex Datagrid header rotation

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer

I have a custom headerrenderer for a datagrid.I have rotated the text to 90 and it works fine. When I try to rotate the text to 270, the text isn't fitting in the header row. I understand that the text starts at the left top and so while rotating it goes outside the header.Is there anyway to fix this 270 rotation issue?I have attached two image,one for 90 degree rotation and another for 270 rotation.

**Header text rotated to 270**

[image]

**Header text rotated to 90**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use

> headerHeight

to define exact height if you can. Or make a custome renderer and apply using

> headerRenderer

to customize almost anything.

Comment: Thanks Harit.The proposed solution will result in image 2. But I want it to be from bottom to top facing right instead of the otherway around. However, I fixed it by using a button in the headerrenderer instead of label.